# Allow a password protected page to be shared on social media?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

I have a password protected site where users can create profiles and add photos. The site uses PHP and Mysql to store user data and pictures.

Can anyone tell me how I might allow users to share a particular page on social media (mostly Facebook) that would allow others with the link to view the particular page, and only that page, even though they have not created their own account on my site.

I can't figure out how this is done so any advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: This question can't be answered without more information. How are the pages protected? A MySQL based login system? A `.htaccess` file? Secondly, how is the perticular page in question written? Where's the code? How does it check if a user is logged in? Is it based on sessions? Is it based on cookies? Or again `.htaccess`?

Comment: share the password, or create a login system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Published links must be public and not behind any password protection, or Facebook will not be able to parse the Open Graph tags. If you want other users to be able to view that particular page, you would need to add a flag to the URL - which would also allow Facebook to get to the Open Graph tags.

For example: `https://yourdomain.com/somelink/?facebookshare=true`

If the GET parameter exists, show the page and ignore user authorization.

Comment: Don't forget to mention that's a huge security hole... Everyone who find out about the GET-parameter can use it on your website. And that's everyone who opens the page from Facebook share. Also, it has to be said that you can't copy a normal link then and place it on Facebook. It's only possible with a build-in share option in your website.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful and gives me an inkling how it might be done.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have two issues here:

1. Having the content "indexed" for the Facebook sharing dialog or direct URL sharing on FB
2. Letting users access the protected site if they clcik on the shared link.

Solutions I'd suggest are:

- Checking the User Agent string. FB will use an agent string that contains `facebookexternalhit/1.1` Be aware that this can be easily forged by other parties as well.
- Checking if the referrer contains `www.facebook.com` if the users arrive at your site unauthenticated

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler