# (PHP) How to share to Facebook from a private blog?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a site where users can create posts inside different groups/categories. Some of these groups are private groups and require user to join the group.

If the group is public and available to anyone without login-in the share Facebook button loads the article in a proper way. However, if the group is private and require a user to sign in and be a member of the group the share button loads only the base URL.

I understand how this happens, simply FB can't bypass login or access the group if not a member.
But I wonder if there is a way to do this since the user is already signed in and inside the group with a started session?

I use standard FB API share button with PHP:

```
<div class="fb-like" style="margin-left: 55px;" data-href="<?= Config::get('URL') . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

Now the only way is to have a user manually copy and paste the address bar URL and post it on their FB wall.

I wonder if Facebook share button could still maintain `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` even though is not accessible?

Comment: I found similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831407/allow-a-password-protected-page-to-be-shared-on-social-media

Answer (score -1):

Try create proper meta tags: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters

```
<meta property="og:url"                content="http://www.nytimes.com/2015/02/19/arts/international/when-great-minds-dont-think-alike.html" />
<meta property="og:type"               content="article" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="When Great Minds Don’t Think Alike" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="How much does culture influence creative thinking?" />
<meta property="og:image"              content="http://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/02/19/arts/international/19iht-btnumbers19A/19iht-btnumbers19A-facebookJumbo-v2.jpg" />
```